# Unity Thought There Was No MonoDevelop In Scripts in My Code

Tags: unity, c#, monobehaviour

Weird Unity thinks that the code that I've checked already has a MonoDevelop inside of it, but unity doesn't think so, can you help find what I wrote wrong in these two scripts?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Freezable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float freezeDuration = 5f; 
    public float unfreezeDuration = 2f; 
    public Material frozenMaterial; 
    public Material normalMaterial; 

    private bool isFrozen = false; 
    private Renderer renderer; 

    void Start()
    {
        renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isFrozen)
        {
            freezeDuration -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (freezeDuration <= 0)
            {
                Unfreeze();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Freeze()
    {
        if (!isFrozen)
        {
            isFrozen = true;
            renderer.material = frozenMaterial;
            Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (rigidbody != null)
            {
                rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
            }
            Collider collider = GetComponent<Collider>();
            if (collider != null)
            {
                collider.enabled = false;
            }
            Invoke("Unfreeze", freezeDuration);
        }
    }

    public void Unfreeze()
    {
        isFrozen = false;
        renderer.material = normalMaterial;
        Rigidbody rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        if (rigidbody != null)
        {
            rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
        }
        Collider collider = GetComponent<Collider>();
        if (collider != null)
        {
            collider.enabled = true;
        }
        Invoke("Freeze", unfreezeDuration);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TimeController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float slowTimeScale = 0.5f;
    public float fastTimeScale = 2f;

    private bool isSlowingTime = false;
    private bool isFasterTime = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            isSlowingTime = true;
            Time.timeScale = slowTimeScale;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            isFasterTime = true;
            Time.timeScale = fastTimeScale;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Q) && isSlowingTime)
        {
            isSlowingTime = false;
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.E) && isFasterTime)
        {
            isFasterTime = false;
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the file name of each of these script files?

Comment: For future use of this site, keep in mind: **1.** when you get feedback that a [prior version of your question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/205327/39518) is unclear, you should *edit that question*, rather than posting a new copy. **2.** Don't tag questions [tag:unityscript], unless they actually relate to this deprecated language - what you have here is C#. **3.** If you're asking about `MonoBehaviour` (a Unity class), don't write it as [MonoDevelop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop) in your question - that's the name of a IDE that no longer ships with Unity.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem when I put the provided scripts into a new project, with the file names Freezable.cs and TimeController.cs, respectively. What steps are required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @INDO_GEMENG, Can you tell us the exact error messages ?